# How to describe streamer?

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-request

Nowadays many people like streaming to share their life, personality, happiness or excitement of gaming, and a streamer might have many different topics/interest to share. How to describe those things by a word so I can say: "His channel features A, B, C, ..., etc". I have found that the platform Twitch uses "Categories" but I'm not sure whether this is suitable for me, since my need is to create column name for a table of name Streamer, but the interest of different streamer might differ a lot. For example some streamers only stream about IRL(In Real Life, and some just playing game, and maybe some have a lot, and the interest of a streamer is not fixed, it might change in every year. Is there any better choice than "Categories"? My intuition tells me its kind of vague.

Comment: Try [features](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/feature)

Comment: I suppose 'Type', 'Subject', 'Content' or 'Category' could all work. It might help you decide on the column header once you have populated some rows with content.